# Concatenating 2 BASH variables is throwing up weird value

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I've got some variables that are being passed through various machines (via php and other bash scripts) and eventually ending up on the last server.

I'm using these variables to populate a mysql database entry.

It all works fine until I try to concatenate 2 of the variables together for one of the entries which results in a completely wrong variable being entered in to the database.

This is an example of the variables as they arrive at the script :

```
$4=48
$6=101216
```

And the script runs fine if I use them individually :

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=xxxx --password=xxxx db_name <<EOF
insert into db_table (uid, ts_id) values ('$4', '$6');
EOF
```

As expected the uid field gets populated with 48, and ts_id gets populated with 101216

But if I try to concatenate them for a third field...

```
userID="$4";
trackID="$userID$6";

mysql --host=localhost --user=xxxx --password=xxxx db_name <<EOF
insert into db_table (uid, ts_id, track_id) values ('$4', '$6', '$trackID');
EOF
```

... instead of 48101216 being entered into the track_id field I'm getting 8388607

Is there some weird math going on or is this an error code being generated?

I've also tried concatenating them like this :

```
trackID=$4$6;
```

Like this :

```
trackID="$4$6"
```

And like this :

```
insert into db_table (uid, ts_id, track_id) values ('$4', '$6', '$4$6');
```

But they all result in the mystical 8388607 ??

Even if the numbers in both variables are different each time I run it, I always end up with 8388607 when I concatenate them?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this way `"${4}${6}"` ?

Comment: @Giovani just tried it.. 8388607.. lol, what is going on?

Comment: MAybe I've got some hidden whitespace at the end of one of the variables?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I need to concat something in bash script I use `{} with ""`. For example: 
`DB_FILE="${FOLDER_NAME}/${CDB}.sql"`
`"${DB_FILE}.bz2"`

Comment: Yes that should work. I think the issue is with the allowed integers in the db column as mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the definition of your track_id column?  Three byte integers allow values in the range of -8388608 to +8388607.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8769

Comment: it's set to mediumint(9)

Comment: Yep this was it. Never run up against this one before. There's a first time for everything ;) Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the column definition in the database to see if it can hold the value you are inserting.